# Проверка input поля на введенные значения

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Делаю проверку на `input` в котором должна быть только латиница.

```js
function validNameCard() {
  var inputValue = $('#credit_card_name').val();
  var regex = new RegExp($('#credit_card_name').attr('regex'));
  if (!regex.test(inputValue)) {
    $('.holder').addClass('errorDate');
    showError('Введите верное значение');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required 
       type="text" 
       onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
       onblur="this.placeholder = 'IVAN IVANOV'" 
       name="card_holder" 
       tabindex="5" 
       minlength="3" 
       maxlength="255" 
       class=" inputs latin-only silver ui_creditcard error validate"                      id="credit_card_name" value=""
       placeholder="IVAN IVANOV" regex="[ A-Za-z]{3,}" />
```

Но получается, что регулярное выражение пропускает такие символы, как ***0*** и прочие, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function valid_cart_name(_this){
  _this.value = _this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/, "");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required 
       type="text" 
       onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
       onblur="this.placeholder = 'IVAN IVANOV'" 
       oninput="valid_cart_name(this)"
       name="card_holder" 
       tabindex="5" 
       minlength="3" 
       maxlength="255" 
       class=" inputs latin-only silver ui_creditcard error validate"                      id="credit_card_name" value=""
       placeholder="IVAN IVANOV" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,}" />
```

При вводе мы убираем все что не подходит.

Comment: а без уберания?) как то можно) такой способ я уже реализовал) но хотелось бы, или же нельзя вообще ввести все кроме латыни, или же срабатывала проверка после сабмита)

Comment: @СергійЧуйко я добавил атрибут pattern он отвечает за проверку введенных данных при отправке формы